# How to receive HTTP using C# when the responding server does not send back any HTTP headers?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, webclient, webexception

I am trying to receive HTTP content from a small embedded Chinese device. The device's inbuilt web server accepts headers but does not return any on the response.

ie

Raw Response: (2 lines, 1 is the XML the second is blank \n)

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><document><userkey>key</userkey>    <machinemode>1</machinemode><serial>0000</serial><unitname>Device</unitname><version>1</version></document>\n`

Fiddler will not show the response at all. Using `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient` yields no results as there are no headers in the response and this results in an exception. Some of the research I have done points to adding the `useUnsafeHeaderParsing` into the application config (and/or setting it programmatically). This does not work at all. I still receive

`System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)`

Is there a work around for this? Without using Sockets/TCPClient is there an alternative way of receiving data from a server that provides no headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get WebClient nor HttpWebRequest to work for accessing the response in such a scenario, so unfortunately i think you're left with [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) :(

Comment: The response property of the `WebException` is null and the status is `ServerProtocolViolation`. You had my hopes up for a second though.

Comment: Sorry - I tried a few things with WebClient, WebRequest, and HttpWebRequest, but couldn't get anything to work.  In case it helps, I put up a quick sample using TcpClient and TcpListener. :)  https://gist.github.com/2622054

Comment: Thank you very much for your code sample. I had also tinkered with TcpClient as well and was preferring not to take that path, but looks to be the only option. My code didn't use `await` and was not able to read the entire stream if the response was over the buffer. Please edit the question to suggest the use of `TcpClient` and I shall mark it as answered. Thank you once again for your time :)

Comment: Combining `TcpClient` `NetworkStream` and this http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html to result in a blocking reader - which is the requirement.